# Running Anaconda as administrator macOS Catalina

Tags: python, permissions, anaconda

I know this has been asked before, but there was no satisfactory answer. I am having a lot of permissions issues with Anaconda and Spyder, so I am trying to run the Navigator as an administrator. My profile is an admin on my laptop, but that doesn't seem to matter. Running `sudo open /[path]/Anaconda-Navigator.app/` is giving me the message "Anaconda Navigator cannot be run with root user privileges". I am running the most up-to-date version of Anaconda, in fact I did a clean reinstall twice this week trying to work out the permissions issues. Is Anaconda just broken now on Catalina?

Comment: Did you use `sudo` when you installed anaconda?

Comment: No, I was specifically installing it for my user only. It's installed on my home directory, but I can't run any conda commands without `sudo` and the Navigator and Spyder are clearly not getting the permissions they should have. Even using `chmod` on folders in the path to test and see if that helps (folders that shouldn't require it) result in the same errors.